# Laravel 5: Change navbar if user is logged

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm completely new to Laravel, MVC and templating engines in general.

I need to show certain navbar buttons and options if a user is logged in such as: Notifications, Logout, Profile, etc... and a Login button otherwise.

Any help on how I could address this the right way is greatly appreciated.
This is what I'm considering at the moment:

- A `User` object is always passed to the view.
- The view checks if the `User` is set (meaning it's logged in) to include the appropriate partial blade template for the navbar.

app.blade.php:

```
...
@if (isset($user))
     @include('partials.navbarlogged')

@else
     @include('partials.navbar')
...
```

Is this the best method?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you create the User model yourself or are you using Laravel's built in User model?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181574/extending-layout-inside-conditional-if-causing-duplication-of-layout) should appropriately answer yours too.

Comment: `@guest ... @endguest`

Answer (score 88):

If you are using Laravel 5's built in User model you can simply do

```
@if (Auth::check())
  //show logged in navbar
@else
  //show logged out navbar
@endif
```

Comment: I'm not using the default Auth mechanisms, so that won't work, will need to find a way to get it to work with my custom OpenID authentication. But it looks like I'm in the good direction in terms of templating. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I would avoid passing the entire User object around, so maybe a small auth helper is in order? Create your own helper file so you can do all of the messy code in there, so in the template you could do something like `Auth::check()`

Comment: What would be the recommended location for that new class?  In fact the entire User object isn't needed. Would it be reasonable to store the needed fields from it in the Session (name, image_url, email, ...) and read from the Session directly in the view? Thanks once again.

Comment: Storing specific values in the session is preferable to storing the entire object, but preferably you would not need to pass the User object or any values of it unless you need to specifically access them. Create an auth facade to handle authentication. The documentation instructs on how to create a facade: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades

Answer (score 54):

For laravel 5.7 and above, use @auth and @guest directives.Here is the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade)

```
@auth
   // The user is authenticated...
@endauth
@guest
   // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

You may specify the authentication guard that should be checked when using the  `@auth` and `@guest` directives:

```
@auth('admin')
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest('admin')
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Otherwise, you can use the @unless directive:

```
@unless (Auth::check())
    You are not signed in.
@endunless
```

Answer (score 30):

New versions of Laravel (5.6 at time of writing) support these two directives in Blade:

```
@auth
// The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
// The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

See official documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `Auth::guest()`

The `Auth::guest()` method returns true or false.

**Example -**

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
    <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
@else
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}">Logout</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 5):

This should help :

```
@extends(Auth::check() ? 'partials.navbarlogged' : 'partials.navbar')
```

The `Auth::check()` sees whether the user is logged in or not and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Laravel 5.4 there's new blade directive `@includeWhen` which includes view based on a given boolean condition :

```
@includeWhen(Auth::check(), 'partials.navbarlogged')
@includeWhen(Auth::guest(), 'partials.navbar')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5's built-in User model you can simply do:

```php
@if (Auth::check())
   //show logged in navbar
@else
   //show logged out navbar
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the `@auth` and `@guest` directives ([see docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#authentication-directives)). An example from the documentation

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth
 
@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```