# Extending layout inside conditional @if causing duplication of layout

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, authentication, laravel-5

I'm working on laravel 5.5. I'm checking whether the user is logged in like this :

```
@if(Auth::check())
//some logic

@else
//somelogic

@endif
```

But the if/else statement is getting executed twice depending whether the user is logged in or not. Why do you think that's happening? 
I have tried other ways to check authentication as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333291/laravel-5-change-navbar-if-user-is-logged). Still I'm getting the same error.

The layout I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', '') }}</title>  

   <!-- Styles -->
   <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">

    @include('inc.navbar')
      <div class="container">
     @yield('content')
  </div>
  </div>

   <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The logic to implement

```
@if(Auth::user())
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h1> Exercises</h1>
@endsection
 @else
  @extends('layouts.app')

  @section('content')
  <h1> Nope</h1>
 @endsection
@endif
```

Comment: Can you share what is the exact issue? This code in itself seems fine. What's `//some login` and what's the output you're getting and what's expected.

Comment: Expected output: Different navbars for a guest user and a logged-in user.
Current output ; The logged-in-user-navbar appearing twice if the user is logged-in. Else the guest-user-navbar appearing twice when the user is logged-out.

Comment: The behaviour you've described indicates that you have an issue independent of your auth check, given you're describing the same content appearing twice. You need to share the layout code you're using, you probably have a mistake there.

Comment: So the authentication part is working just fine. In which page are you including this blade template file and how? Check for repeats.

Comment: I will edit the question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your page like this. `@extends` should not be called twice.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')
    @if(Auth::user())
      <h1> Exercises</h1>
    @else
      <h1> Nope</h1>
    @endif
  @endsection
```

You can also use a ternary operator if you want different layouts for extend :

```
@extends(Auth::check() ? 'layouts.app' : 'layouts.app2')
```

Comment: Use a ternary operator to check and change the layout. You shouldn't and in most cases cannot use the `@extends` twice without duplication. Updated the answer with required code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
@if(Auth::user())

// User is logged

@else

//User is not logged

@endif
```

I hope this will be useful

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5 you can use something like that

```
@auth
   // logged in
@else
  // not logged in
@endif
```

Also, you can check for guest user

```
@guest
  // guest user 
@endguest
```

For more info read [Authentication Directives](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#if-statements)